# Merge 2 arrays of objects in only 1 with a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Lets have a look an example:

```
var arr1 = new Array({name: "lang", value: "German", carId: 1}. {name: "lang", value: "German", carId: 3});
```

I need to merge this two arrays and convert that carId into a list with those values:

```
({name: "lang", value: "German", carId: [1,3]});
```

Comment: Do you have to check both? `name` and `value` for merging?

Comment: Yes, I have check them

Comment: "Let's have a look (at) an example" of what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code

```
var arr1 = new Array({ name: "lang", value: "German", carId: 1 });
var arr2 = new Array({ name: "lang", value: "German", carId: 3 });

const result = arr1.map((o) => {
    let item

    arr2.forEach(
        (o2) => {
            if (o2.name === o.name && o2.value === o.value) {
                item = { name: o.name, value: o.value, carId: [o.carId, o2.carId] }
            }
        }
    )

    return item
}).filter(item => item)
```

Methods used (that may confuse):

- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var arr1 = new Array({name: "lang", value: "German", carId: 1});
    var arr2 = new Array({name: "lang", value: "German", carId: 3});

    var mergedArray = arr1.concat(arr2); //merged the two arrays
    var cardIds = {}; // to collect the cardsIds for same name and value

    // collect the cardsIds for same name and value
    mergedArray.map((item) => {
     var key = item.name + '_' + item.value
     cardIds[key] = cardIds[key]? {...cardIds[key], item.carId}: [item.carId]
    })

    // Get unique element from merged array by name and value
    var result = _.uniqBy(mergedArray, (o) => {return o.name && o.value});

    // get the result with name, value and their cards in the array.
    result = result.map((item) => {
     var key = item.name + '_' + item.value
     item.cardId = cardIds[key]
     return item
    })
```